# HighStock : Remove Zoom bar

Tags: highcharts

I want to remove the parts of the highStock as shown in the picture. 
They dont make sense in my data formatting . 
Please help

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/cpvLzLso/

```
rangeSelector: {
    selected: 4,
    inputEnabled: false,
    buttonTheme: {
        visibility: 'hidden'
    },
    labelStyle: {
        visibility: 'hidden'
    }
}
```

We are simply hiding all texts and buttons.

And user is able to change default chart interval by changing a `selected` parameter in `rangeSelector` settings group.

But you'd better use a Jugal's solution if you don't need to disable navigator bar.

**UPD 1:** Updated on 23/06/15 to meet today's realities. To all of you who downvoting this answer: try to disable a navigator in Jugal's answer and then pan a chart.

Comment: also check this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726094/highstock-show-preview

Comment: This does not remove the part circled on the right. Jugal's answer about disabling the rangeSelector seems to be more complete. It also uses HighStock settings directly to just not create it rather than having it created and looping through a bunch of items to hide them.

Comment: @Igor what happens exactly when you try to pan with my solution? Btw the default range in my jsFiddle is *all*, so you will have to zoom in before you can try panning. And navigator is the master chart we see at bottom & rangeSelector is the what the OP has circled in red. You have also disabled the navigator?

Answer (score 21):

Highchart supports this out of the box by setting the enabled property of the [rangeSelector](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector) to false as follows

```
rangeSelector:{
    enabled:false
}
```

[disabled RangeSelector @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/QFZFb/)

Comment: If you have chart with disabled navigator, you will not be able to pan and zoom chart.

Comment: Check Jugal's jdFiddle. It works. The rangeSelector is not the same as the navigator.

Comment: Just had checked mine old answer. @Jack.R.Abbit, see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/QFZFb/26/ - it's Jugal's Fiddle with disabled navigator. You can't pan or zoom this chart - just what I said three years ago. Next time try to reproduce a glitch before sending "It works", mate :)

Comment: @IgorShastin Your first answer (before you edited it) didn't do what the OP asked for and included stuff the OP didn't ask for. Jugal's jsFiddle worked for what the OP asked for... not what you asked for. I stand by my comment, mate.

Comment: New API link: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove the "From to" boxes you can do like this:

```
rangeSelector:{
   inputEnabled: false,
}
```

If you want to remove every range selector you have to write that row:

```
rangeSelector:{
    enabled: true,
}
```

And if you want to do the zoom buttons disabled, you have to write this

```
rangeSelector:{
    allButtonsEnabled: true,
}
```